# Why are there no Preview event handlers in UWP?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

In WPF, for most UI events, we have `PreviewX` event as well. How come there is no such a thing in Universal Apps? Is the events system fundamentally different from that of WPF that there is no need for it?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, the system has changed from bubbling and tunneling. Now it works with Routed Events. More information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview). Here is the important excerpt:

> Earlier we said that setting Handled to true prevents most handlers from being called. But the AddHandler method provides a technique where you can attach a handler that is always invoked for the route, even if some other handler earlier in the route has set Handled to true in the shared event data.

So instead of adding the event handler as usual, you'll need to call `AddHandler` to add your "Preview" handler.

*Something to note:* the documentation does not say that these special handlers are executed before the regular ones, so it is not exactly the same as the `PreviewX` method.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I had read several times the Microsoft Document about Routed Events without realizing that there's no tunneling in UWP Tap events. I think your answer should be marked as a solution.Anyway, I have tested and the handler attached to a container is not executed before. The only difference is that I can make it run even if the internal handler sets Handled property to true.